# Ensure child processes get killed if Parent Process crashes in python.Solution must support all operating system

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system, parent-child, ipc

I have an application where a parent process polls a server to get download jobs and then spawns child processes to complete the job.This cycle continues until there are some jobs to be entertained by the parent process.I need to ensure that the child processes die in case the parent process crashes.I am using python as programming language.Plus let's say in case this parent process dies it is brought up by some other process. Below are some mechanisms -
 1. As per multiprocessing module of python - "When a process exits, it attempts to terminate all of its daemonic child processes." So it attempts but does not guarantee.So its not reliable.
 2. I can add entry in db with the mapping of child_process_id->jobId, which tells which child process is downloading which job.When the parent process comes up before polling it checks whether there is any entry of child_process_id->jobId. In case there is it kills the process with given child_process_id and sends the jobId in the next poll. 
 Can I have a clean way of killing the child processes when parent process crashes abruptly ?I need to have a solution compliant for windows, linux and mac. I was suggested by someone that File Locks can help me but i could not understand how file locks can help me achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
#parent.py

import time
import subprocess
import file_lock_lib
import os

PARENT_LOCK_NAME = "ParentChildTask"
CHILD_LOCK_NAME = "ChildTask-%d"


def main():

    #for running single parent process
    fmutex, res = file_lock_lib.FileLock(PARENT_LOCK_NAME, True)
    print("PARENT ID is =============" + str(os.getpid()))
    if not res:
        print("ParentProcess already running")
        exit(1)

    print("Spawing Child Processes")
    r = subprocess.Popen(["python", "/Users/abi/PycharmProjects/osProgramming/parent_child/child.py"])
    #aquire the lock for child process
    c_lock, res = file_lock_lib.FileLock(CHILD_LOCK_NAME% r.pid)

    import time
    start_time = int(time.time())
    while (int(time.time()) - start_time) < 180:
        a = 1
    1/0
    #file_lock_lib.FileUnlock(fmutex)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


#file_lock.lib.py

import sys
import os

if sys.platform != 'win32':
    'NOOB_IDS fcntl sysv_ipc sendmsg'
    import fcntl




def FileLock(fname, nb=False):
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        try:
            sa = w32s.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES()
            sa.SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(True, None, False)
            fmutex = win32event.CreateMutex(sa, False, fname)
        except pywintypes.error as fault:
            if fault.winerror == 5:
                fmutex = win32event.OpenMutex(win32event.SYNCHRONIZE, False, fname)
            else:
                raise

        if nb:
            wtime = 0
        else:
            wtime = win32event.INFINITE

        rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(fmutex, wtime)
        if rc == win32event.WAIT_TIMEOUT or rc == win32event.WAIT_FAILED:
            win32api.CloseHandle(fmutex)
            return None, False
    else:
        if not fname.startswith('/'):
            # Not an absolute path name, prefix in $HOME/.inSync
            fname = os.path.join(os.getenv('HOME'), '.file_lock_lib', fname)

        fdir = os.path.dirname(fname)
        if not os.path.exists(fdir):
            os.makedirs(fdir)

        try:
            fmutex = open(fname, "rb+")
        except:
            fmutex = open(fname, "wb+")
        try:
            flags = fcntl.LOCK_EX
            if nb:
                flags |= fcntl.LOCK_NB
            fcntl.flock(fmutex.fileno(), flags)
        except IOError:
            return None, False

    return fmutex, True


def FileUnlock(fmutex):
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        win32event.ReleaseMutex(fmutex)
        win32api.CloseHandle(fmutex)
    else:
        fcntl.flock(fmutex.fileno(), fcntl.LOCK_UN)
        fmutex.close()


#child.py

import time
import subprocess
import file_lock_lib
import os

PARENT_LOCK_NAME = "ParentChildTask"
CHILD_LOCK_NAME = "ChildTask-%d"


def main():
    print("CHILD PID  =================" + str(os.getpid()))
    #check if parent process is running
    fmutex, res = file_lock_lib.FileLock(PARENT_LOCK_NAME, True)
    if res:
        file_lock_lib.FileUnlock(fmutex)
        print("Parent process is not running")
        exit(1)

    print("Child Started")
    #spwan a thread to do work

    #wait on Parent
    mtx, res = file_lock_lib.FileLock(CHILD_LOCK_NAME%os.getpid())
    file_lock_lib.FileUnlock(mtx)
    print("Child Exited as parent process was killed")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I figured out a way to solve the issue. Consider the parent and child process from the code above.
Hope this solution works....